# HttpWebRequest increases latency

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, gzip

I have a piece of code that I have noticed after prolonged use begins to increase the latency on my computer.  The requests slowly get longer and longer and through SpeedOf.Me, my latency visibly increases. The only thing that seems to cure the latency is resetting my modem.  Am I not correctly closing connections or releasing resources? Why is this happening?

```
var request = HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);

using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
using (GZipStream zip = new GZipStream(response.GetResponseStream(), CompressionMode.Decompress, true))
using (StreamReader unzip = new StreamReader(zip))
{
    string str = unzip.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming you have nested **usings** since your post does not show the opening/closing braces.  Since **HttpWebRequest** does not impl IDisposable, there's not much to do there.  Can you use a different client like **HttpClient** - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: How did you measure latency?